# When using pd.read_csv, is there a way to exclude certain rows based on their contents when identifying the header?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use `pd.read_csv` to open and modify many different `.dat` files. An example of what these files look like is as follows:

```
  #Data file
  #Information on column 1
  #Information on column 2
  #Information on column 3
  col1 col2 col3
  data data data
```

Different `.dat` files have the same general format, but may have different columns, so different numbers of inital rows explaining the columns and the data they contain. This means that I can't just hardcode the `header` parameter when I am iterating throughout the files.

I have tried to hardcode the `header` to the smallest row number I'd use and it seems to have put everything in the right order, but I want to exclude the information rows when creating my header. Is there a way I can do this when I am using the read function? I'd also like to keep the information rows at the top of the file where they are.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to specify `comment=` parameter:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('your_data.csv', sep=r'\s+', comment='#')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0  data  data  data
```

---

Contents of `your_data.csv`:

```
#Data file
#Information on column 1
#Information on column 2
#Information on column 3
col1 col2 col3
data data data
```